# AWS Apache2 This Site can't be reached

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04

After installing and running Apache2 on my EC2 Instance (Ubuntu 16.04) in AWS, I want to access the Site from my public browser with "ec2-3-231-162-52.compute-1.amazonaws.com". Apache2 is running on port 80, and I already created a security group, which allows Port 80 to connect. So why can't I access the default apache2 website?

Apache2 running status:

[image: 1]

Security Group Incoming Traffic:

[image: 2]

Security Group Outgoing Traffic:

[image: 3]

Comment: 2 things - 1) are u sure apache running 2) have u set up security group correctly?

Comment: @RavindraBagale Thanks for your reply, I just added the screen snippets to the post. Not 100% sure if the security group is defined correctly. Apache2 ist running I believe..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need quite a few pieces to make sure this is working:

- First, your EC2 instance, and a running HTTPD server. Sounds like you have that.
- Then, you'll need a VPC for the pieces to sit in.
- You'll need a subnet on the VPC.
- You'll need a route table in the subnet.
- You'll need a security group on the VPC.
- Your EC2 instance will need a public IP on the subnet.
- Finally, an internet gateway to expose the VPC to the public internet.

Requests will flow through the internet gateway into the VPC, use the route table to find where they should go, and arrive at your EC2 instance, where the security group you've set up allows them into the correct port.